# If I remove `ssh` from public zone and retain only rich rules in trusted one, will I be able to reach my server?

Tags: linux, firewall, firewalld

I have the following (multiple empty entries are omitted):

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --list-all-zones
block
  target: %%REJECT%%
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  masquerade: no


dmz
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  services: ssh
  masquerade: no


drop
  target: DROP
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  masquerade: no


external
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  services: ssh
  masquerade: yes


home
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  services: ssh mdns samba-client dhcpv6-client
  masquerade: no


internal
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  services: ssh mdns samba-client dhcpv6-client
  masquerade: no


public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp2s0
  services: dhcpv6-client https ssh
  ports: 50036/tcp
  masquerade: no

trusted
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  masquerade: no
  rich rules:
        rule family="ipv4" source address="myip1" service name="ssh" accept
        rule family="ipv4" source address="myip2" service name="ssh" accept
        rule family="ipv4" source address="myip3" service name="ssh" accept

work
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  services: ssh dhcpv6-client
  masquerade: no
```

If I do

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --remove-service=ssh --permanent
```

Will I be able to reach my server then? I am confused by the fact, that `trusted` zone has no any sources and not marked `active`. Why do I have only one zone active.

Also I don't see `timeout` option service removal command.